# TTL configuration and billing in Azure Integration Runtime

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Doing some tests, I could see that having an Azure Integration Runtime (AIR) allowed us to reduce considerably the amount of time required to finish a pipeline.

To fully understand the use of this configuration and its billing as well, I've got these questions. Let's assume I've got two independent pipelines, all of their Data Flow activities use the same AIR with a TTL = 10 minutes.

The first pipeline takes 7 minutes to finish. The billing will be (if I understand well):

billing: time to acquire cluster + job execution time + TTL  (7 + 10)

Five minutes later, I trigger the second pipeline.  It will take only 3 minutes to finish (I understand it will also use the same pool as the first one). After it concludes, the TTL is  setting up to 10 minutes again or is equal to 2 minutes
10 - 5 -3 (original TTL - start time second pipe - runtime second pipe), in this case, what will happen if I trigger a third pipeline that could take more than 2 minutes?
What about the billing, how is it going to be calculated?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the ADF pipeline monitoring view and find all of your data flow activity executions.

Add up that total data flow activity execution time.

Now add the TTL value for that Azure IR you were using to that total.

That is the total time you will be billed.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that part of my doubt is clear, but regarding the first part, when the VM pool is warm-up,  if I have selected 10 minutes, that is all the amount of time that I have to execute sequentially other pipelines using the same cluster. Am I right?

Comment: TTL keeps the cluster alive for new job executions for 10 mins *after* your previous job completes